# Graphviz command '['dot', '-Tdot']' returned non-zero exit status -11

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphviz

I want to extract the coordinates calculated for my graph by Graphviz. However, I'm running into the following error with Python 2.7 and Graphviz 0.9:

```
Graphviz command '['dot', '-Tdot']' returned non-zero exit status -11
```

I cannot find any documentation on these error codes. Below is the code I'm using:

```
gvz = GraphUtils.toGraphvizGraph(graph)
parsed_dot = gvz.pipe('dot')
```

The first line turns my own graph representation into a Graphviz Digraph instance.

```
result = Digraph()

# By hashing the ids, we get rid of any potential special characters graphviz does not like
# A graphviz ID always needs to start with a character
for node in graph.nodes.to_dict(orient='records'):
    result.node('id_{}'.format(abs(hash(node[node_name_key]))), 'label for width')
# END LOOP

for edge in graph.edges.to_dict(orient='records'):
    result.edge('id_{}'.format(abs(hash(edge[edge_source_key]))), 'id_{}'.format(abs(hash(edge[edge_target_key])), edge[edge_label_key]))
# END LOOP
return result
```

The second line transforms the graph into DOT, which contains the coordinates I need. However, this is where my error occurs.

While testing, I found that occasionally my node ids would contain illegal characters ([as defined here](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html)). I eliminated these cases by transforming all my ids into hashes. Now all my node ids look like this:

```
['id_7598267142946574759', 'id_2914022568081909736', 'id_2112657658742367456', 'id_2416843868423017323']
```

This has eliminated the error for some of my graphs, but not for all of them. Since the error code is still the same, I'm thinking there must still be something wrong with these ids. However, since the error code is not actually defined anywhere, I might also be looking in the wrong direction. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you have a collision? Two nodes with same id?

Comment: Good point. However, the error occurred with the set of IDs listed above, which doesn't contain any collisions.

Comment: When possible create the dot file of the failing graph for inspection, or otherwise at least make a file with the ids as you are using in that file.

Comment: The set of ids listed above is the complete set of ids from one of the graphs for which the error occurs. Unfortunately I'm not able to export as dot, since that's where the script fails.

Comment: `-11` is a SIGSEGV -- a segfault; it means `dot` crashed hard, as by trying to dereference a null pointer (or more generally a pointer pointing at memory the process doesn't own). Generally, you should be able to reproduce that with no Python involved at all, by feeding the same input to the stdin of your `dot` command at a shell. Doing so with gdb attached is likely to be the right place to start in debugging the issue at hand.